# how to add a multiple buttons inside a groupbox in wpf?

Tags: wpf, button, groupbox

I need to add a multiple buttons inside a groupbox in wpf, but I can't. I need to create my key pad for an atm machine, with all numbers, but if I try to create a button number 2, the button number 1 disappears.
what is wrong?

```
<Window x:Name="Win_Users" x:Class="ATM_Simulator.WindowUsers"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ATM_Simulator"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="WindowUsers" Height="300" Width="500">
<Grid>
    <GroupBox x:Name="grbx_key_pad" Header="Key Pad" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="220" Margin="26,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189">
        <Button x:Name="btn_1" Content="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="29" Height="32"/>
    </GroupBox>
    <GroupBox x:Name="grbx_select_transaction" Header="Select Transaction :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="88" Margin="291,23,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="179"/>
    <GroupBox x:Name="grbx_select_account" Header="Select Account" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="92" Margin="291,138,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="179"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn_submit" Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="291,239,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn_close" Content="Close" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="393,239,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="77"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You should use `RowDefinitions` and` ColumnDefinitions` for your `Grid`. With a solid design you lose many advantages. As you do this, you see for example in this tutorial: https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/grid-rows-and-columns/

Answer (score 1):

You have to put a container inside the GroupBox, for example a Grid would be a good choice:

```
<GroupBox x:Name="grbx_key_pad" Header="Key Pad" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="220" Margin="26,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
        <Button x:Name="btn_1" Grid.Column="0" Content="1" Width="29" Height="32"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn_2" Grid.Column="1" Content="2" Width="29" Height="32"/>
        <!-- more buttons -->
        <Button x:Name="btn_4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="4" Width="29" Height="32"/>
        <!-- yet more buttons -->
    </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's my first project on wpf, I'm struggling a lot, also my first language, so it means I know just a little bit. I tried, but it says the property "content" is set more than once.   I have no idea what to do.

Comment: I could add my first column with three buttons, 1,4 and 7( I put inside a stackpanel), but I cant now add a second column..... :(

Comment: Use a Grid instead, with 3 columns and 4 rows. Or, in your StackPanel, put 3 more StackPanels and add buttons to those. But a Grid is more elegant in this case.

Comment: You can express your thanks by accepting the answer ;)